# problem of normal distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

The annual income of a head physician is normally distributed.
If 25% of the head physician  earn less than 180 000  and 25% of them earn more than 320 000, what is the percentage that earn:

(a) less than 200 000

(b) between 280 00  and 320 000?

Let X be a  normal random variable  that represents the annual income of a head physician (every unit correspons to a  thousand).
$$P(X< 180)=0,25$$ e $$P(X > 320)=0,25$$

$$P(X> 320)=1-P(x<320)=1-P((X-\mu )/\sigma  \le (320-\mu )/\sigma )=0,25$$
$$P((X-\mu )/\sigma  \le (320-\mu )/\sigma )=0,75 \approx\Phi (0,675)=P((X-\mu )/\sigma \le 0,675 )$$
Then $$ (320-\mu )/\sigma=0,675$$

$$\Phi (0,675)\approx 0,75\Rightarrow  \Phi (-0,675)=1-\Phi (0,675)=1-0,75=0,25$$

$$P((X-\mu )/\sigma  \le (180-\mu )/\sigma )=0,25 \approx\Phi (-0,675)=P((X-\mu )/\sigma \le -0,675 )\Rightarrow  (180-\mu )/\sigma =-0,675$$

Then I calculate $$\mu=250$$ and $$\sigma=103,70$$

$$P(x<200)=P((X-\mu )/\sigma  \le -0,4821 )=0,75=\Phi (-0,4821)=1-\Phi (0,4821)=0,3156$$

$$P(280<X<320)=P(x<320)-P(x<180)=2*\Phi (0,0,675)-1=0,5$$

But the solution for the second question should be $$0,136$$

why?

Comment: In the last line it should be $P(x<280)$ instead of $P(x<180)$ I think.

Comment: I was going to say as comment above - but also note that 280 is above the mean of 250 you calculated, therefore (280, 320)  cannot apply to 50% under the normal distribution - 0.5 has to be wrong

Comment: I got it thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your answer, you have a typo where you write $P(X < 180)$ where it should be $P(X < 280)$. Therefore, we get:
$$P(280 < X < 320)=P(X < 320)-P(X < 280)=0.75-P\left(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} < 0.289\right)$$
Now, according to my calculator, the latter probability is $\approx 0.613$, so we get:
$$0.75-0.613=0.136$$